# Docusaurus move div element to side of the screen

Tags: css, reactjs, docusaurus

I have some experience in React, but have limited experience in docasurus and have been trying to create a non-static page in my docasurus build. The issue is, if you create a new page and create a div element, the div element only takes up approximately 70% of the horizontal width. Each side has about 15% screen width set aside to be used for static sidebar generation. On my non-static page, is there anyway to adjust the div element to move it to the part of the screen locked away for side bar generation?

Ex code so far:

```
export const TestComponent = ({}) => {
  return(
    <div style ={{backgroundColor: "blue"}}>
      Test
    </div>
  )
}
```

If this code is ran in a docasurus build on a new page, you'll see the div takes up approximately 70% of the screen with the blue background color. I already tried other css properties such as marginRight, but these have not shifted the base position of the div element.